# Cannot remove new line character in python

Tags: python

I have this code which connects to a SQL database, fetches all the rows and splits them to a `.from` file and a `.to` file. Previously, before adding the rows to the database, I've gone and replaced every new line character (\n) with "`newlinechar`" so that every row in the resulting text files would be an entry. But despite the database having 125000 entries, the output files are more than 100 lines longer which means some entries still contained a "\n" characters I think.
So before adding them to the text files I tried using `replace("\n", "")` on every entry as you can see to be sure there weren't unexpected new lines.

But nothing changes. What am I doing wrong? Why can't I remove the new lines from the entries?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("latest.db")

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM comments')

ns = 0
vals = c.fetchall()

with open("train.from", "w", encoding="utf8") as f, open("train.to", "a", encoding="utf8") as t:

    for row in vals:


        r1 = (row[0].replace('\n', ""))
        r2 = (row[1].replace('\n', ""))
        f.write(r1 + "\n")
        t.write(r2 + "\n")
```

Here's one of the databases entries that still contained a newline character:

```
My last few years was me working as a store manager (minimum 54 hours a week) and going to school part time to avoid taking out loans.
 newlinechar 
 newlinechar It took a while, but I got my degree and it's paid for itself many times over.
```

As you can see, after "loans" there is a "\n" character. But if I remove it "manually" with this code:

```
st = """My last few years was me working as a store manager (minimum 54 hours a week) and going to school part time to avoid taking out loans.
 newlinechar 
 newlinechar It took a while, but I got my degree and it's paid for itself many times over."""

print(st.replace("\n", ""))
```

it gets removed.
But when done in the cycle in the code above it doesn't:
[image]

Comment: Actually print out the line and take a look at it. I'm willing to bet there's a `'\r'` in there as well, that's gumming up the works

Comment: It may be better if you take the original entry and use `str.splitlines()` which will split lines (hopefully) correctly. Then you can `"newlinechar".join(...)` the result to put `"newlinechar"` between each entry

Comment: By the way, you can see the `\n` and `\r` characters of a string by doing `print(repr(s))`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @syntaxVoid for pointing this out:
you can see the special characters in the sentence via `print(repr())`.
After running this function with the sentence above I found '\n' and '\r' that for some reason didn't get deleted and so I removed them using `.replace("\r", "")` and `.replace("\n", "")` in this order and it worked.